# How to delete from db?

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring framework, the following code was use to delete a record, but it failed to worked, why?

```
List<PostAttachment> postAttachments = postAttachmentRepo.findByObjectKey(key, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt"));
postAttachments.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findByObjectKey` is returning collection to you and

```
postAttachments.remove(0);
```

Will remove the record from the collection only and not from the database. So, to remove data from dabase either

1. You need to call `entityManager.remove(postAttachments.get(0))`, for this entity needs to be managed and transaction.
2. Use spring repository method,  `postAttachmentRepo.delete(postAttachments.get(0))` in this case, spring manags everything (transaction as well entity is managed).

Comment: I was aware this was not going to remove calling remove(0), didn't know that's a method in postAttachmentRepo called delete to get it complete removed. Thanks.